# MDM Device token issue

Tags: device, token, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I have setup simple demo for MDM server. I can successfully recover initial plist with messagetype, pushmagic token, APNs token(32byte as base46) and unlocktoken. My issue is when I tried to decode APNs token using base64_decode php function, it returns with  junk/garbage character. Can any help if I need to use anyother php function to decode APNs token?

Thanks,
Viral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token is just what it is: a token. What you're getting with base64_decode is just a byte-array, you cannot see any meaningful data in it or print it as a string. Just store it in binary form in your database. You need this token later on to identify the target device when you send a pending command notification to the APNS. It is the actually the same as a push-token for an app.

The content of the notification for the device is described in [1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html), and the APNS protocol in [2].

**References**

1. Apple Inc, Mobile Device Management Protocol Reference
2. [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, you are correct. I was only confused because when I tried to print that in browser, it shown junk characters, and when used it in push notification, I was not able to received any notification on device, so I thought there should be some issue with decoding method. But I will try with storing byte-array in database and try to use it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto this. If you're using another library to abstract sending notifications, sometimes they expect the `token` to be 64 characters. With PHP, you can do this with `$token = bin2hex(base64_decode($deviceToken));`

However if the `token` is stored in your database as binary format, then the `base64_decode` can be omitted. The following is what is required when dealing with PHP PDO w/ Postgres:

`bin2hex(stream_get_contents($deviceToken))`